# Unable to find source files

Tags: sass, gruntjs, source-maps

I've started working on an existing website at work that uses Sass and auto-prefixer with Grunt. I'm not 100% familiar with the files yet, but I don't want to change the structure to avoid breaking anything. The problem I'm having is that no matter what .scss files I edit, it doesn't affect the required .css file. The developers that originally built the site aren't here anymore.

The changes I make either affect file.css or file2.css, and I need to reach file.expanded.css, but there's no mention of this file in the Gruntfile, so it was either removed, or it's being compiled in another way. Obviously, I'm avoiding editing it directly. I'm just unsure if I have enough to figure this out.

In case it helps, here's the Gruntfile:

```
module.exports = function(grunt){

  require("matchdep").filterDev("grunt-*").forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);

  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    sass: {
      build: {
        files: {
          'assets/css/file2.css': 'assets/sass/folder/file2.sass'
        }
      }
    },

    autoprefixer: {
      build: {
        src: 'assets/css/file.css',
        dest: 'assets/css/file.css'
      }
    },

    watch: {
      css: {
        files: ['assets/sass/**'],
        tasks: ['buildcss']
      }
    },

    // Browsersync
    browserSync: {
        dev: {
            bsFiles: {
                src: [
                    'assets/css/*.css',
                    'assets/images/*',
                    'assets/scripts/*.js',
                    '**/*.html'
                ]
            },
            options: {
                watchTask: true,
                proxy: "site.dev:8888",
            }
        }
    },
  });

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['browserSync', 'watch']);
  grunt.registerTask('buildcss', ['sass', 'autoprefixer']);

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should install a Grunt task for source maps and recompile your CSS. I personally use Gulp so, I'm unsure what the best solution for Grunt might be, but it's a similar set up.  When your CSS is compiled with source maps, you'll be able to pinpoint with your inspector where in which partial or SASS file the style declarations are coming from.

http://thesassway.com/intermediate/using-source-maps-with-sass